# How to build gcc-4.9/libgcc1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb

Tags: gcc, debian, apt-get, deb

I am in need to build gcc-4.9/libgcc1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb locally so that I can copy this deb file to another host for installation.

I am aware that we can build .deb & install file using below steps:

```
# apt-get source gcc version 4.9
# dpkg-checkbuilddeps
# apt-get install <for all packages listed in above command>
# dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
# dpkg -i <package.deb>
```

Please confirm on step and let me know how can I download gcc-4.9/libgcc1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb package cource code to build .deb file? But I am getting below error at first step itself:

```
# apt-get source gcc version 4.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'gcc-defaults' as source package instead of 'gcc'
NOTICE: 'gcc-defaults' packaging is maintained in the 'Svn' version control system at:
svn://svn.debian.org/svn/gcccvs/branches/sid/gcc-defaults
E: Unable to find a source package for version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install required package :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot devscripts
```

**configure apt**

Open your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ,Uncomment the lines that start with `deb-src`

Add the following line:

```
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian unstable main
```

**NB** : **If you use stable distribution, getting source from unstable won't affect it.**

Update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Use the command `apt-get source` to download the source code :

```
apt-get source gcc
```

Once the package is downloaded (`gcc-defaults-1.136`  `gcc-defaults_1.136.dsc`  and `gcc-defaults_1.136.tar.gz`)
, you can check the directory where you are (typing ls), and you'll find that apart from the 3 files that were downloaded you also have a directory, called `gcc-defaults-1.136`. This is the unpacked source of the Debian package.

**Get the build dependencies**

```
 sudo apt-get build-dep gcc
```

**build the package**

```
   debuild -b -uc -us
```